# How to view headers of default JDK HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, http

There's [getHeaderFields()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderFields%28%29) but that returns the headers in the response HTTP message. I want the headers in the request message, not the response.

Also, what is the difference between Properties and Headers? It seems like [setRequestProperty()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is setting a header, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the method getRequestProperties() you'll find your guess is right:

```
public Map<String,List<String>> getRequestProperties()
```

> Returns an unmodifiable Map of general request properties for this
>   connection. The Map keys are Strings that represent the **request-header**
>   **field names**. Each Map value is a unmodifiable List of Strings that
>   represents the corresponding field values.

Comment: Strange naming; why not just getRequestHeaders() and getResponseHeaders()?

Comment: After studying for the Web Components certification exam, all I can say is: the exam would be too easy if the names were consistent :(